# How to call window.matchMedia() correctly in an Angular 2 app

Tags: angular

Once `window` object shouldn't be accessed directly in an Angular application, so you can have a chance to run the app outside the browser, how can I call `window.matchMedia()` in an "Angular way"?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you found a solution but in case you didn't, take a look at [cdk layout - media matcher](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview#mediamatcher)

If you don't want to import CDK layout in your app you can copy the code of the media matcher class from [their git repo](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview#mediamatcher)
it's quite simple and only depends on the CDK platform.

Answer (score -2):

You need to add "matches" at the end:

```
  if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 889px)').matches) {
      //your code
   }
```